# 2013 MacBook Pro crashed, won’t restart

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, restart

I was using Firefox when my MacBook Pro crashed.  I was not initially concerned, as it does this about once a month.  However, it no longer starts.  It had 80% battery when it crashed, and plugging it in does not help.  Before I take it to the shop or take it apart, I hope someone here can offer a solution.
It is a 2013 MacBook Pro running the latest version of Yosemite.

Edit:  The computer restarts after several hours, but crashes again later.  I sought professional advice and was informed that the logic board needed to be replaced, because the not-restarting bit is apparently symptomatic of an overheated logic board.  But the problem resumed two days after a new logic board was installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to reset NVRAM or PRAM (older Mac)? With Mac turned off, power on the Mac, then press and hold CMD (⌘) + Option (⌥) + P + R until restart itself, this should take a couple of seconds. This could be find at [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063), Hope it helps

Comment: When I press (or press and hold) the power button, nothing happens.  If I try to hold the key combination “until restart” then nothing just keeps happening, only now I’ve got sore fingers.

Comment: Um, never mind the problem.  My computer just started up while I wasn’t touching it.  While it was closed.  Which is a little freaky, but problem solved… I guess?

Comment: if the problem was solved congrats... 
I had to apply that combination, when my computer is suspended with a virtual machine running

Comment: It did it again.  I wasn’t running a VM.  Actually, I’ve noticed a common thread (although I have a sample size of 2):  both times I have had this problem, I was running the newest version of Firefox.

Comment: I don't  know, the only time i have had that problem as i already mentioned, it was when the VM was running and the mac goes to sleep. I do not use too much Firefox but, maybe it is a Bug or something like that...